# Exclude a given string from the given list in terraform

Tags: terraform

I would like to exclude a given string from the list of string in terraform

example:
I have following data source as a variable

```
region_list = data.oci_identity_region_subscriptions.region_subscriptions.region_subscriptions.*.region_name
```

Now, I would like to exclude a region from it. Region "us-ashburn-1"

exclude ("us-ashburn-1") form region_list. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: If any one of the below answer has satisfied your query. I would mark this question as resolved by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 26):

Easiest way to get rid of a `set` of values in another `set` is to use [`setsubtract()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setsubtract.html):

```
locals {
  regions = ["us-west-2", "us-west-1", "us-east-2", "us-ashburn-1"]
}

output "excluded" {
  value = setsubtract(local.regions, ["us-ashburn-1"])
}
```

outputs:

```
excluded = [
  "us-east-2",
  "us-west-1",
  "us-west-2",
]
```

if you want to keep the order or duplicates in a list, then using a `for` expression as already mentioned in another answer is preferred.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by using for loop and if condition in terraform.

Example terraform configuration,

```
variable "regions" {
  type    = list
  default = ["us-west-2", "us-west-1", "us-east-2", "us-east-1"]
}

output "excluded" {
  value = [for region in var.regions : region if region != "us-east-1"]
}
```

The above config will output all the region except us-east-1.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

```
excluded = [
  "us-west-2",
  "us-west-1",
  "us-east-2",
]
```